# buffer i/o experienced on Debian 10.8

Tags: linux, debian, thinkpad

For a little while now, my thinkpad randomly has the following issue while running Debian 10.8 and I have no useful resources online as to how to resolve it. I am running it on a Thinkpad T480

[image]

Comment: What's the question? The `sda` device seems to be dying. Or it is underpowered and misbehaves. Or data connection cable is broken. See SMART at least, and please reformulate your post as a *question*.

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: @DavidPostill I feel this is too strict in this case. It is possible they can't just copy it as a text, this picture seems to be a phone photo. But, to help properly we need to see exact `dmesg` messages. It is quite cruel to force users to retype it.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov It's meant as a suggestion ...

Comment: @DavidPostill if I can get directions or pointers on how to get my system to print those logs to a file so that I can paste it here, I would be more than happy to.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a message about an I/O error means there is a problem with the drive.  While it is possible that problem is a firmware problem, cable problem, or a problem with power, usually it means the drive is dying.

You can boot off a live CD and run `smartctl -t short /dev/sda` (package `smartmontools` if it's not already installed) and then, once the test is done, run `smartctl -l selftest` to see the results.  Usually this will provide you with an overall summary of the state of the drive, but if not, you can run `smartctl -x` to see that.

In my case, it says this:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

which means my drive is in a good state.  I suspect yours will not say that, and you will need to replace your drive.  There is no way to effectively repair a broken drive without specialized equipment, so replacement is it.

If the drive reports that it's good, you could then look into things like changing out the cable or querying the power supply via `/proc` to see if those are the cause of the problem.  But, in my experience, those are less common than drive mortality.

Comment: thanks, I will do that first and see what the results are.

Comment: I tried that and I also got `PASSED`. do you have any suggestion on what to look at next?

Comment: Then it could very well be the cable to your drive.  If that's bad, it can definitely cause failures.